# What makes the left engine on a conventional twin-engine aircraft the critical one?

Tags: aircraft-performance

I already know that this is because of P-factor. But I don't know how to draw a picture or explain this simply?

Comment: [Wikipedia on P-factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-factor) has sufficient picture to give a clue why. And it depends on the direction of propellers rotation: it may be left, right or even none (for counter-rotating props, like on PA-44 or P-38).

Answer (score 4):

The "critical engine" (as it is called in this context) is based on the direction of propeller rotation and the "arm" length from the descending blade to the aircraft's center of gravity.

Here is a picture and explanation (source: [Skybrary](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Critical_Engine))

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was there a reason why the P-38 had both engine rotating top side away from the fuselage? It would seem to be no advantage in doing this whatsoever.

Comment: @CharlesBretana Sounds like a new question.

Comment: I would think that being a military aircraft rather than a civilian one, the trade-off is handling over stability. The outer lever arm increases the moment and as a result the rate of turn. this is much more important when you are being shot at vs heading to the local fly in for a serving of heart attack on a plate.

Comment: @RowanHawkins: The P38 along with many other military and civilian airplanes have "counter-rotating" props that along with a few advantages did not have the disadvantage of a "critical engine."

Comment: @757toga nothing I said disagrees with that. The question is about a civilian plane. The P-38 has counter rotating props which places both moment arms further from the center axis -- the fuselage. This gives them a larger moment arm and results in a tighter turn. The civilian ones as noted above have the moment closer to the fuselage which instead increases stability. The question asked in the comment above is why the choice was made between inboard and out board lever since they felt they were equivalent. From a critical engine stand point they are. From a handling standpoint they are not.

Comment: @757toga from a totally nitpicking level in the counter rotating prop example, planes with inboard down props have no-critical engine. Outboard on the other hand has 2 based on the P-factor. The choice between the options is also the difference between military planes and their choice of performance over stability vs civilian ones.

Comment: @RowanHawkins: by "critical engine" I'm referring to the one engine that if inop would result in the worst asymmetrical thrust (from the other engine). As long as they are counter rotating engines one, if inop, is not worse than the other in this regard.